# Get return value of python class function after timer

Tags: python, timer, return, return-value

I have a simple python class called Timer_ that takes an interval in seconds and runs the timer in the background. When it is done, it runs a finished function that returns true. How would I get the value of this function when the timer stops in the form of a variable? Thank you!

```
import threading



class Timer_():

    def __init__(self, interval):
        #interval in seconds
        self.interval = interval
        self.finished = False

    def run(self):
        self.timel = threading.Timer(float(self.interval), self.finish)
        self.timel.start()

    def finish(self):
        self.finished = True
        return True

    def cancel(self):
        self.timel.cancel()



time = Timer_(5)
time.run()
print(time.finished)
```

Comment: So you want to wait until the timer finishes?

Comment: Yes when the timer finishes I would like to store a python variable outside of the class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - Using global variables in a function - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to wait until `time.finished` is `True`

Try using a while loop over the value of `time.finished`:

```
time = Timer_(5)
timer.run()
while not timer.finished:
    pass
x = timer.finished
print(x)
```

This will loop through the while until `timer.finished` is `True` then you can use that value as a variable or continue on.